# Mudar background do aplicativo em "aplicativos recentes"

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Como mudar o background do aplicativo quando clica no botão quadrado (aplicativos recentes)?

Eu já pesquisei e alguns indicaram usar o `onPause` e `onStart` para mudar o background utilizando

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Só que quando vai ter mudança de tela, ele acaba setando o background. Por isso preciso saber se tem como setar esse background apenas quando aperta o botão que mostra os app recentes (quadrado).

Meu objetivo é esconder o conteúdo da activity quando houver mudança de aplicativo ao apertar o home e reabrir o aplicativo quando aperta o quadrado.

Este é o botão citado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Parecido com esse exemplo desse aplicativo para iOS
[image: Parecido com esse exemplo desse aplicativo para iOS]

Comment: Eu alterei a imagem por uma menor pra não poluir muito a publicação.

Comment: Obrigado ! jbueno !

Comment: Você colocou o `setFlags` antes do `setContentView`?

Comment: No final das contas eu acabei usando essa solução: 
` @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (!hasFocus) {}` só que o problema é que ele é chamado até quando tem a transição de uma tela para a outra.

Comment: Acho que se houver o evento de click nesse botão já resolveria o problema ! Já que usando o onPause, não deu certo, porque ele é chamando quando há a troca de contexto, quando muda de uma activity pra outra.